# E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')

Tags: android, react-native

I am compiling a release APK and I am getting this error message when the app start :

```
E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')

E/ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules Process: com.packaged, PID: 26481
                                         com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.length'), stack:

                                                   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:56)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:40)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

It is clear this is the issue **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')** the problem is that I do not know which variable is exactly and how to validate, because it only happens when I am compiling a release APK

Comment: Can you paste the code for the component that is being called in AppRegistery?

Comment: `import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);` @ShubhnikSingh

Comment: Seems to be a bug with react native 0.50.1, try downgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was having a conflict with another dependency. I cleaned up my `package.json` file. for instance in this case I removed `native-base` and this fixed it